# При открытии файла или папки он удаляется

Tags: windows, windows-7

*Возникла такая проблема на Windows 8:*

При нажатии на любой файл (папка, файл, даже "мой компютер" в проводнике), система начинает удалять этот файл или папку. Думал что  переустановка решит проблему, но даже после того как поставил Windows 7 проблема осталось. 
***Помогите не знаю что делать !!!***

Вот такое выдает при нажатии на "Мой компютер" в поводнике:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: возможно вирус, установите антивирус

Comment: @Saidolim, перед тем как переустановить винду, проверил на вирусы, но ничего не обнаружело... Потом переставил и при первом включении такое ...

Comment: клавиатура чудит?

Comment: @zRrr, скорее всего

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По всем симптомам запала клавиша `Delete`. Потычьте её раз 25, может, пройдёт.

Comment: перестает, но потом опять начинает так делать ....

Comment: Значит, клавиатуре явился полярный пушной зверёк. Поменяйте.

Comment: думаю, что чистка клавиатуры поможет...